# Is there a way to convert a entry textbox in tkinter into a variable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Im trying to print x,y,z, and w  after they been assigned a number in the entry widget in a press of a button so once I press  the button x,y,z, and w will print

```
Curve1_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 1')
Curve1 = Entry(canvas)

Curve2_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 2')
Curve2 = Entry(canvas)

Curve3_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 3')
Curve3 = Entry(canvas)

Curve4_lb = Label(canvas, text='Curve 4')
Curve4 = Entry(canvas)

Curve1.pack()  
Curve2.pack() 
Curve3.pack()
Curve4.pack()
Curve1_lb.pack()
Curve2_lb.pack()
Curve3_lb.pack() 
Curve4_lb.pack() 

x = Curve1
y = Curve2
z = Curve3 
w = Curve4   

btn = Button(canvas,text='Print',relief=SOLID, command = prints)
btn.pack(pady=10)
                                                                                   
def prints():
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
    print(w)
```

Comment: It is better to use tkinter variables for this

Comment: @PCM There is no need for a `tkinter` variable here. The only time you would use a `tkinter` variable in a `tkinter.Entry` is when you need to trace that variable. Adding a `tkinter` variable to an entry without tracing that variable is completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `x` is just another reference to the `Curve1` widget.  To get the contents of the widget, you have to call `get`:

```
from tkinter import *

canvas = Tk()

Curve1_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 1')
Curve1 = Entry(canvas)

Curve2_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 2')
Curve2 = Entry(canvas)

Curve3_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 3')
Curve3 = Entry(canvas)

Curve4_lb = Label(canvas, text='Curve 4')
Curve4 = Entry(canvas)

Curve1_lb.pack()
Curve1.pack()
Curve2_lb.pack()
Curve2.pack()
Curve3_lb.pack()
Curve3.pack()
Curve4_lb.pack()
Curve4.pack()

def prints():
    print(Curve1.get())
    print(Curve2.get())
    print(Curve3.get())
    print(Curve4.get())

btn = Button(canvas,text='Print',relief=SOLID, command = prints)
btn.pack(pady=10)

canvas.mainloop()
```

It's also possible to create a "live" connection between a widget and a local variable, but that's not really necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

try using x as

```
x = Curve1.get("1.0","end") #this will get all the text in the entry widget
print(x)
```

Comment: You can't pass in any arguments when calling `<tkinter.Entry>.get()`. You are thinking of `<tkinter.Text>.get()` which needs 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I will not say this is the better approach but alternative. It is bit lengthy but try this once, it's alternative of your code.

```
from tkinter import *

canvas = Tk()

c1=StringVar()
c2=StringVar()
c3=StringVar()
c4=StringVar()

Curve1_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 1')
Curve1 = Entry(canvas,textvariable=c1)
Curve1_lb.pack()
Curve1.pack()

Curve2_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 2')
Curve2 = Entry(canvas,textvariable=c2)
Curve2_lb.pack()
Curve2.pack()

Curve3_lb = Label(canvas,text='Curve 3')
Curve3 = Entry(canvas,textvariable=c3)
Curve3_lb.pack()
Curve3.pack()

Curve4_lb = Label(canvas, text='Curve 4')
Curve4 = Entry(canvas,textvariable=c4)
Curve4_lb.pack()
Curve4.pack()

def prints():
    print(c1.get())
    print(c2.get())
    print(c3.get())
    print(c4.get())

btn = Button(canvas,text='Print',relief=SOLID, command = prints)
btn.pack(pady=10)

canvas.mainloop()
```

We are creating new variable for every entry and saving it in `c1`,`c2`,`c3`,`c4` respectively.

Comment: There is no point to using a `StringVar` and attaching it to an entry, if you aren't going to trace it. It's much simpler to just use `<tkinter.Entry>.get()`. Using a `StringVar` in this case is completely pointless and makes your code way longer.

Comment: Yeah! I know that, I had told OP that also in answer!

Comment: No, I am telling OP there is alternative to solve there problem, is giving alternatives wrong? If there is no value of `StringVar()` then why is this made? I am just tell OP that there is this alternatives, not tim's answer is only answer to solve your problem!

Comment: There is no use for `StringVar()` unless you are calling `.trace(...)` on it (if you are attaching it to an entry)

Comment: Then I should delete my answer?